# How to get current date from kendoDatePicker not in the 'change' handler

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-datepicker

Those approaches don't work:

```
dateSelectedFrom = $("#datepickerFrom").value - undefined
dateSelectedFrom = $("#datepickerFrom").value() - object has no method value()
```

I know that I can use `this.value()` and it is works fine, but the method `onDateSelectedFromCalendar` is used by a different dateTimePicker control (I have several on the page)

```
<input id="datepickerFrom" value="10/10/2011" />

   $("#datepickerFrom").kendoDatePicker({
            change: onDateSelectedFromCalendar
        });

   function onDateSelectedFromCalendar(e) {
        dateSelectedFrom = $("#datepickerFrom").value;
    }
```

Documentation doesn't specify any other options
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/datepicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Kendo object you have to use `data` like:

```
var d = $("#datepickerFrom").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value();
```

See the [documentation here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/datetimepicker#methods-value).

Comment: What if I only want the date and not the time? How can i get the date part alone?

Answer (score 1):

You can have all the datepickers calling the same onChange event using the below:

```
function onDateSelectedFromCalendar(e) {
    dateSelectedFrom = e.sender.value();
}
```

if you wanted to be able to distinguish which element triggered the function you could use:

```
e.sender.element[0].id
```

which will give you the Id of the element.

Lastly

```
e.sender
```

will give you the same as

```
$('#datepickerFrom').data().kendoDatePicker
```

Check their DatePicker api [Here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/datepicker/api.html)